# Divide one div in 2 rows

Tags: php, html, css, divide

Is there any possibility to divide this elements into 2 rows displaying one by one?
I cant just make class="row1" ="row2" because of structure...

PHP:

```
<div class="newses">
    <div class="mid_header">
        <h3>Aktualności</h3>
        <div class="heading_border"></div>
    </div>
    <?php for ( $i = 0, $counted = count($last_articles['newses_date']); $i < $counted; ++$i): ?> 
        <div class="srpart2_data"<?php print ( !$i ? ' id="srpart2_data_first"' : '' ); ?>>
            <?php print ( $last_articles == null ? $internal_langs['data_is_empty'] : $last_articles['newses_date'][$i] ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="srpart2_title">
            <?php print ( $last_articles == null ? $internal_langs['data_is_empty'] : $last_articles['newses_title'][$i] ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="srpart2_tresc">
            <?php print ( $last_articles == null ? $internal_langs['data_is_empty'] : $last_articles['newses_content'][$i] ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="srpart2_links">
            <div class="srpart2_links_part1">
                <a href="<?php print base_url() . 'main/show/' . $last_articles['newses_id'][$i]; ?>"><?php print $internal_langs['main_go_to_news']; ?></a>
                <img src="<?php print base_url(); ?>system/application/views/img/<?php print $script_lang; ?>/ar_lightgray.gif" alt="Arrow" />
            </div>
            <div class="srpart2_links_part2">
                <a href="<?php print base_url() . 'newses/'; ?>"><?php print $internal_langs['main_go_to_news_archive']; ?></a>
                <img src="<?php print base_url(); ?>system/application/views/img/<?php print $script_lang; ?>/ar_lightgray.gif" alt="Arrow" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

I know its messy but its not my code and best way if i couldn to not change the structure of it.

EDIT: I mean I dunno anything about PHP :( If it could be done b css, but it probably cant.

LaughDonor: heres the webiste: [www.bossini.pl](http://bossini.pl) and im trying to display box "aktualnosci" in 2 columns, it is code I put above.

Comment: Are you saying you cannot change the PHP file you provided, or you don't want to change it because of the associated CSS? There's a difference, as it will determine the route you take to fix it (PHP fix, vs. CSS and/or Javascript).

Comment: add a `<br>` wherever you need one.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish? More code on what you've tried, examples, or pictures can help!